# recursion - Not sure why the numbers increase and then decrease 1234554321

Tags: c, recursion

I am currently learning the basics of C, and I came across this code. The main function calls `Count()` and passes 1. And in `Count()`, 1 is printed and since cnt is less than 5 it'll keep on calling itself and therefore continue to print out 1 2 3 4 5.

After, cnt is 5, then it'll print out 5 and then since cnt is = 5, so it'll print out 5 again (won't satisfy the if condition statement).

```
void Count(int cnt){
    printf("%d\n", cnt);
    if(cnt < 5){
        Count(cnt + 1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", cnt);
}

int main(){
    Count(1);
}
```

I thought the output would simply be 1 2 3 4 5 5, but I don't get why its 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1.

An easy-to-understand explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: When you call `Count(1)`, it prints `1`, then calls `Count(1 + 1)`, then prints `1`.

Comment: Besides needing to learn a little more about *recursion*, it might also be a good time to learn how to use a debugger and how to use it to step through your code line by line.

Comment: Every time you call `Count()` it's a new (recursive) invocation of the function. The old invocation is still active, waiting for the current invocation to end. Imagine instead of calling `Count()` you call `Count1(1)`, then `Count2(2)`, `Count3(3)`, ...

Comment: Surprisingly I only found a C++ duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547253/recursion-with-functions-in-c/33547337

Answer (score 2):

First thing to notice is that you have two `printf` statements in each `count` function. So you will print the passed number `cnt` two times in the function.

The second thing you need to know is how the functions are called.

`count(1) -> count(2) -> count(3) -> count(4) -> count(5)`  At `count(5)` the function will not call any further `counts`.

Up to here you have printed `1 2 3 4 5`

The return will be `count(5) -> count (4) -> count (3) -> count(2) -> count (1)`

Before each return you will print respectively `5 4 3 2 1`

Finally you get

> 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! So I was wondering how we return ```count(5) -> count(4) -> count(3) -> count(2) -> count(1) ```

Comment: When you call the functions recursively count(1) -> count (2) -> count(3) etc the information of the function (internal variables, program counter etc) is pushed in something called a stack. So when `count(5)` returns `count(5)` is removed from the stack, and what is at the top of the stack is `count(4)` which is executed next.

Answer (score 0):

The first `printf()` prints all of the numbers counting up, as each new call to `Count()` adds another call frame to the stack. This prints

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

Once the `if` condition (which makes the recursion continue) is no longer met, no more recursive calls are made, which allows the recursion to end and the last `printf()` (located *after* the `if` condition) for the *most recent stack frame* now runs. This prints the 2nd `5`. The stack frames on the stack now "unroll", from most recent to least recent, allowing each function call/stack frame to run to completion and thereby perform it's 2nd `printf()` statement, which now comes out in reverse order (including the `5` I just mentioned above) as:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Remember that recursion adds stack frames for a given function call, and only *after* recursion stops going deeper (the end condition is met) does the latter part of the function, after the recursive call to `Count()`, for each stack frame, now in reverse order on the stack, begin to *get run to completion*, releasing each stack frame from the stack as each recursive function call on the stack runs through to the end of the function.

Answered from my phone. <s>Forgive the lack of formatting.</s>
Fixed!